# JAVA Swing GUI Components howto RTL view?

Tags: java, swing, right-to-left

How can i make my Java Swing GUI Components [Right To Left] for Arabic language from NetBeans Desktop Application?

Comment: Do yo mean, how to display text, in a JLabel for instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't you just have to use:

```
Component.setComponentOrientation( ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT )
```

I believe that the swing components all already have support for RTL, don't they?

Not sure how/where you'd do that in regards to netbeans, though.

Comment: There's also Component.applyComponentOrientation(..) to change a whole component tree.

Answer (score 5):

The call of

```
 Component.setComponentOrientation( ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT )
```

should do the trick. But be sure to use the SwingConstants LEADING and TRAILING instead of LEFT and RIGHT in your layouts. The same goes for GridBagConstraints.LINE_START or LINE_END instead of WEST or EAST, and probably some similar cases which I forgot to mention.

Comment: That's a great answer, the information about using the more meaningful alignment constants may not be a given to others having trouble with this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use alignment, but that would not handle the complexities if you have English letters or numbers embedded within your text.

It might be preferable to use some sort of styled text widget or even an embedded HTML/rich text viewer.

I don't think that standard JLabels can handle the complexities otherwise.

Comment: JLabel display unicode letters. I think they relay on the system fonts and if the system fonts can display the letter then everything it's ok. For instance in my comp I can write "Extraño"

Answer (score 0):

you could use it if you have components inside panels inside contentPane

```
        Component[] component = contentPane.getComponents();
    for(int i=0; i<component.length; i++){
        component[i].applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        Component[] cp = ((Container) component[i]).getComponents();
        for(int j=0; j<cp.length; j++){
            try{
                ((Component) ((JComboBox) cp[j]).getRenderer()).applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            }catch(Exception e){
                continue;

            }
        }
    }
```