# netbeans displaying jlabel-text right to left

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, arabic

I want to develop a java desktop application  for arab people 
so I need that arabic labels be displayed correctly from right to left

I am using netbeans. How can I chang the text orientation ?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354745/java-swing-gui-components-howto-rtl-view will be of some use to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the GUI builder, right click the labels and other components, choose `Properties` and the you can set the text alignment.

Or, if creating GUI writing code, use the [setHorizontalAlignment method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalAlignment%28int%29).

Comment: what about Jtable , I need that the header be oriented from right to ledt also . I  didn't found such proporiety

Comment: @nawara right-to-left properties are defined automatically by the local, as I understand it