# How Change Netbeans Java Application objects to "right to left"

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I need to display objects on frame from "right to left"?

[image]

same program in C# 
Thats what I want the objects look like

[image]

please help me :) 
Thank you

Comment: seems to be a java and not a netbeans specific question - can you show us the code?

Comment: Drag and Dropped objects from netbeans, I didn't write the GUI

Comment: [JAVA Swing GUI Components howto RTL view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354745/java-swing-gui-components-howto-rtl-view)

Comment: I didn't realize the windows bar was orientation dependent..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change component orientation by calling `setComponentOrientation()` method for each component you want to use arabic inside it, for combobox your should override its cell renderer to support right to left displaying, try the following code:

```
public class Test extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    public Test()
    {
        setBounds(100,100,380,400);
        setTitle("بوابة العالم");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"التاريخ","الفلسفة","الفلك"});
        comboBox.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        comboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,comboBox.getPreferredSize().height));
        comboBox.setRenderer(new CellRenderer());
        add(comboBox);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        textPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textPane);
        scroll.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        add(scroll);

        setVisible(true);
    }

}

class CellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer<String>
{
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends String> list, String value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(value);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setFocusable(true);
        label.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        if (isSelected) {
            label.setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
            label.setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
            label.setBackground(list.getBackground());
            label.setForeground(list.getForeground());
        }
        return label;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

For title bar orienation it will not work for you if you are using the host look and feel for title bar, but it works if you call `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)` then your app will use the provided look and feel and not the host one, next you should call `setComponentOrientation()` method on your frame to specify the desired orientation, try this code to activate right to left for title bar:

```
public class Test extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);  
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    public Test()
    {
        setBounds(100,100,380,400);
        setTitle("بوابة العالم");
        setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"التاريخ","الفلسفة","الفلك"});
        comboBox.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        comboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,comboBox.getPreferredSize().height));
        comboBox.setRenderer(new CellRenderer());
        add(comboBox);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        textPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textPane);
        scroll.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        add(scroll);

        setVisible(true);
    }

}

class CellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer<String>
{
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends String> list, String value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(value);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setFocusable(true);
        label.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        if (isSelected) {
            label.setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
            label.setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
            label.setBackground(list.getBackground());
            label.setForeground(list.getForeground());
        }
        return label;
    }
}
```

Result :

[image]

NB:

- Don't forget to save your source files using UTF-8 encoding to support arabic characters.
- `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)` must be called before creating any frame instance.

Comment: No, this works fine, if I wrote the code myself.
But, I draw the objects/components from netbeans.

Comment: @NickMichael when you finish your design you can disable protection of generated code in netbeans by editing your source file in external editor (like notepad++) and remove all pairs of comments that contains GEN-BEGIN and GEN-END then reload your file into netbeans and then go to source view and modify your code. Warning: when you remove GEN-BEGIN and GEN-END comments netbeans will not be able anymore to generate automatic code for you.

Comment: @NickMichael if you want to edit freely your code anywhere inside your application use eclipse with windowbuilder plugin for swing.