# Align values in JTable cells to right-to-left while Editing

Tags: java, jtable, alignment

I have the following table
[image]

I found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408541/align-the-values-of-the-cells-in-jtable) code to align values in "كوردى" column to Right-To-Left.
It works fine, But when i edit cells the align becomes Left-To-Right as shown at the above Image,
What i do to align values to Right-To-Left while editing ?

Comment: changenthe default editor for the column to support your requirements

Comment: I'm wondering if something like [ths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354745/java-swing-gui-components-howto-rtl-view) will help, although i thought the locale aet this kind of thing up

Comment: i found it thanks look at the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the my answer, Thanks for all

```
 JTextField textField = new JTextField();
 textField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
 DefaultCellEditor dce = new DefaultCellEditor( textField );
 table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(dce);
 textField.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Comment: I think you set the component orientation globally using [`Component#applyComponentOrientation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#applyComponentOrientation-java.awt.ComponentOrientation-) on the top level component

Comment: but i have some TextFields in my project that are Left-to-Roght